# React Native Paper Dark Theme on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-darkmode, react-native-paper

I want to use react-native-paper dark theme on my apps, however, all my `<View>` are still had a white background and causing all the Text component unreadable because the text turns white in dark mode. I didn't use custom theming since the docs mention that:

> If you don't use a custom theme, Paper will automatically turn animations on/off, depending on device settings.

This is my code in App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider as PaperProvider} from 'react-native-paper';
import Home from './src/Home';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <Home />
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is in my Home.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {Appbar, Card, Title} from 'react-native-paper';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Appbar.Header>
        <Appbar.BackAction onPress={() => console.log('back')} />
        <Appbar.Content title="Title" subtitle={'Subtitle'} />
      </Appbar.Header>
      <View>
        <Title>Hello World</Title>
        <Card
          style={{margin: 15, padding: 15}}
          onPress={() => console.log('press card')}>
          <Title>This is Card</Title>
        </Card>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

and this is the result:
[The view still white and the Title also white due to dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91qUl.png)

[It working fine on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsg6l.jpg)

The text turns white because it is the behavior of dark mode, but why my `<View>` is still white? This is only happening on iOS, it works fine on android.

This is a new react native project, and based on documentation in react-native-paper it will turn the dark theme automatically. So, I need help if I missed something in setting up this project on iOS. Any help would be appreciated.

- react: 16.13.1
- react-native: 0.63.4
- react-native-paper: ^4.7.1
- react-native-vector-icons: ^8.0.0

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify a custom theme, Paper will use the DefaultTheme which is essentially a light theme. To employ a dark theme in your app, Paper provides a Material based DarkTheme. You can specify which theme to use within the Paper provider.

Complete example from the docs for DefaultTheme including customization:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DefaultTheme, Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import App from './src/App';

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  roundness: 2,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    primary: '#3498db',
    accent: '#f1c40f',
  },
};

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

PaperProvider uses React Context. Theme can be accessed within components with the withTheme HOC or useTheme hook.